# Nested Children Json in Angular HTML

Tags: html, json, angular, nested

I have a JSON with nested children. RowElements can have *n* colElements and colElements can have *n* RowElements.

JSON

```
"container": {
    "id": "37ec0632-3391-4ef5-a9cb-25db2216fa75",
    "rowElements": [
        {
            "id": "80e1dae7-b497-48d3-80ad-b94d36ada642",
            "colElements": [
                {
                    "id": "c662efe9-615c-4de5-97d3-2b02a5bce831",
                    "rowElements": [
                        {
                            "id": "b31960fd-c082-4d3b-88fc-c05f0cf837aa",
                            "colElements": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "7552306a-ca61-4d80-bb4e-d6c8d15c2c78",
                            "colElements": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "f669896d-132b-468e-8dcf-f2b59d509a76",
                            "colElements": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can i iterate over the children dynamically in the template like:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
         </div>
         <div class="col">
         </div>
         <div class="col">
         </div>
         ...
      </div>
      ...
   </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your broken code.

Comment: I do not have any broken code. My question is about how to iterate through such a dynamic json.

Comment: your solution is write a recursive function. do you want to access to the children's ids ?

Comment: The idea is you write code. When it breaks, we help fix it. But since you don’t have broken code, there’s not much we can do.

Comment: @AlirezaEbrahimkhani yes I would like to access the properties such as the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `*ngFor` to iterate the JSON and display it dynamically.

I also created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwupjl?file=src/app/app.component.html) for you to check my solution.

**HTML** - I'm display the id here just to check the JSON.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let firstRow of arr.container.rowElements">
  {{ firstRow.id }}
  <div class="col" *ngFor="let firstCol of firstRow.colElements">
    {{ firstCol.id }}
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let secondRow of firstCol.rowElements">
      {{ secondRow.id }}
      <div class="col" *ngFor="let secondCol of secondRow.colElements"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**AppComponent.ts** - I added a variable to hold your sample JSON

```
export class AppComponent {
  arr = {
    container: {
      id: '37ec0632-3391-4ef5-a9cb-25db2216fa75',
      rowElements: [{
        id: '80e1dae7-b497-48d3-80ad-b94d36ada642',
        colElements: [{
          id: 'c662efe9-615c-4de5-97d3-2b02a5bce831',
          rowElements: [{
              id: 'b31960fd-c082-4d3b-88fc-c05f0cf837aa',
              colElements: []
            },
            {
              id: '7552306a-ca61-4d80-bb4e-d6c8d15c2c78',
              colElements: []
            },
            {
              id: 'f669896d-132b-468e-8dcf-f2b59d509a76',
              colElements: []
            },
          ],
        }, ],
      }, ],
    },
  };

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.arr.container);
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem here ist that i have 4 static for-loops. But the last empty col-Element can have one more row element and the row element can have one more col element. That is dynamically json.

I need an algorithm to iterate dynamically through the lists.